# Cant launch programs like chromium browser or steam

Tags: startup-applications

When I try to lauch chromium through the terminal, nothing happens. No feedback at all, just blank.
When I try to launch it through the gui, I can see it loading in the top left corner but after a while it disappears but nothing launches. The same thing happens with steam and firefox. I have tried reinstalling chromium and steam yet nothing changes.

Comment: Are you using the snap or deb versions of those apps, and on which version of Ubuntu are you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what I have done before.
Try this.

```
sudo apt remove chromium-browser
sudo apt purge chromium-browser
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

Then.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install
chromium-browser
```